# Shopify Php fulfillment its giving me a 404 error

Tags: shopify

I have an app made in php and it no longer allows me to fulfill orders, this is giving me a 404 error.

this is what i have

```
    function fulfill_order_by_id($order_id,$tracking_number){       
        $url=shopi_api_url().'orders/'.$order_id.'/fulfillments.json';
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $response = $client->request('POST', $url,['form_params' => [
            'fulfillment'=> [
                'location_id' =>'63110676671',
                'notify_customer' => 'true',
                'tracking_company' => 'Other',
                'tracking_url' => 'https://www.starken.cl/seguimiento',
                'tracking_number' => $tracking_number ]]]);
        $json_body = json_decode($response->getBody(),true);
        return $json_body;
    }
```

i try to update everyting cause i create this app on 2020 i update the api to 2023-07 and i make this.

```
function fulfill_order_by_id($order_id,$tracking_number){   
        $config=connection();
        $shopify = new PHPShopify\ShopifySDK($config);  
        //echo $order_id;
        
            
        try{
            $fulfillment = $shopify->Fulfillment();         
            /*$fulfillment->update_tracking([], // Params
                ["fulfillment" => [, "tracking_info" => ["company" => "Other", */

            $fulfillment->line_items_by_fulfillment_order  = [
                "location_id"=> "63110676671",
                "order_id"=> $order_id,
                "notify_customer" => true
            ];
            $fulfillment->tracking_info = [
                "company" => "Other",
                "number" => $tracking_number,
                "url" => "https://www.starken.cl/seguimiento"
            ];
            echo"<pre>";
            print_r($fulfillment);
            echo"</pre>";               
                        
            $fulfillment->save(
                true, // Update Object
            );
            
        }catch(Exception $e) {
            echo 'Caught exception ' .  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        }       
    }
```

but its giving me this error Caught exception No action named save is defined for Fulfillment

please help

Comment: How is this related to PHP? By the message of the exception (of which the [class-name](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) of the exception has been hidden) this sounds like a problem genuinely related to [tag:shopify]. I've pro-actively removed the unrelated tag. If you think otherwise please edit it again and clarify in your question why you think so.